How do we choose the reactant/product in terms of which we have to express the rate of reaction?
Consider the reaction:
$$ \ce{2HI(g) -> H2(g) + I2(g)}$$
My textbook defines the rate of reaction in terms of the rate of formation of $\ce{H2}$ or $\ce{I2}$ and not in terms of $\ce{HI}$. What is the reason behind this? Is it a convention to define the rate of reaction in terms of the reactant/product whose stochiometric coefficient is 1? If so, then why?
Or do I have the liberty to choose the reactant/product in terms of which it will be defined?

There is nothing to choose. You have such-and-such molecules collide and produce such-and-such other molecules. You count both, and then write down the reaction equation:
$$\ce{2HI(g) -> H2(g) + I2(g)}$$
Now, the rate is defined via "how many times did this exact thing happen", where by "this thing" I mean the act of such-and such molecules colliding and producing other molecules (see above), according to the reaction equation (also see above).
So in case of the said reaction the entire phrase reads: "how many times did two molecules of $\,\ce{HI}$ react to produce one molecule of $\,\ce{H2}$ and one molecule of $\,\ce{I2}$". This is in terms of what the reaction rate is defined, and not in terms of any particular ("main") reagent. There is no convention for choosing the main reagent, no liberty to choose the main reagent, and indeed no such thing as the main reagent at all.
Whether any reactant or product has coefficient of 1 is also irrelevant.
So it goes.

To add to @Ivan's answer, the extent of reaction, $\xi $, is $\pu{1 mol}$ when the reaction as written goes once, i.e., $\pu{2 mol}$ of $\ce{HI}$ reacts to give $\pu{1 mol}$ of $\ce{H2}$ and $\pu{1 mol}$ of $\ce{I2}$. Then the rate of reaction is defined as
$$
v=\frac{1}{V}\frac{\operatorname{d}\xi }{\operatorname{d}t}=\frac{1}{(-2)}\frac{
\operatorname{d}[\mathrm{HI}]}{\operatorname{d}t}=\frac{1}{(1)}\frac{\operatorname{d}[
\mathrm{H}_{2}]}{\operatorname{d}t}=\frac{1}{(1)}\frac{\operatorname{d}[\mathrm{I}_{2}]
}{\operatorname{d}t}
$$
where the numbers in parentheses are the stoichiometric coefficients
(assuming the volume is constant). So any of the species can be chosen and
the numerical value of $v$ will be the same, but this number does depend on
how the reaction is written.
